# Prevent method from returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I'm new to callbacks and trying to get this working. I don't want my getCustomerIdDescription returning anything to my popover until my post has returned data, but I get an error on the 'callback(supplierId)' line at the bottom that says 'callback is not a function' How do I write my callback so that nothing gets returned from getCustomerIdDescription until I have my post data?

Here is my code

```js
scope.showCustomerIdList = function(value) {
  $('#{0}'.format(value)).popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    content: function() {
      return scope.getCustomerIdDescription(value);
    },
    title: function() {
      return 'Customer ID - Description';
    }
  }).popover('show');
};

scope.getCustomerIdDescription = function(supplierId, callback) {
  var model = {};
  model.clientId = scope.contextClientId;
  model.supplierId = supplierId;
  $.post(scope.enumControllers.GetCustomerIdsForSupplier, model, function(response) {
    if (response.error == false) {
      var ids = JSON.parse(response.ids);
      var list = '';
      _.each(ids, function(result) {
        list += '<li>' + result.CustomerId + ' - ' + result.CustomerDescription + '</li>';
      });
      return '<ul>' + list + '</ul>';
    } else {
      return "Cound't Fetch Customer Ids";
    }
  }).fail(function() {
    return "Cound't Fetch Customer Ids";
  });
  callback(supplierId);
};
```

Comment: Do you have a function named "callback"?

Comment: no, I'm a newbie to callbacks. I'm just trying to prevent my function returning undefined before the data comes back!

Comment: @user1186050 — You can't prevent the function from returning before the Ajax response arrives. Ajax is asynchronous. Hence the name.

Comment: ok understood, but what do I need to change so that the function doesn't return undefined and only returns after the data has been sent back to the client?

Answer (score 3):

You call:

```
scope.getCustomerIdDescription(value);
```

But you define:

```
scope.getCustomerIdDescription = function(supplierId, callback) {
```

Since you don't pass it a value, `callback` is `undefined`.

Then you:

```
callback(supplierId);
```

… without testing to see if `callback` is a function or not.

Either:

- Remove that line *or*
- Wrap it in a test that makes sure a function is passed *or*
- Always pass a function as the second argument when you call `getCustomerIdDescription`

Incidentally, there isn't much point in passing a callback function there if you call it as soon as the Ajax request is sent. It normally makes more sense to put it inside the callback functions you set up on the request.

Comment: if I remove the line 'callback(supplierId)' then the function returns before the post has the data sent back.

Comment: @user1186050 — Yes, but if you don't remove it, then the function throws an error and never returns. See also the last paragraph of the answer which discusses the proper place to have a callback.

Comment: can you please give me an example of what you would modify? I tried removing callback(supplierId) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

Just to make your code work try below approach and for understanding the approach and the concept of **Asynchronicity**, Please Visit [Asynchronicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

```
scope.showCustomerIdList = function(value) {
 scope.getCustomerIdDescription(value, function(content){
  $('#{0}'.format(value)).popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    content: function() {
            return content;
    },
    title: function() {
      return 'Customer ID - Description';
    }
    }).popover('show');
 });
}

scope.getCustomerIdDescription = function(supplierId, callback) {
  var model = {};
  model.clientId = scope.contextClientId;
  model.supplierId = supplierId;
  $.post(scope.enumControllers.GetCustomerIdsForSupplier, model, function(response) {
    if (response.error == false) {
      var ids = JSON.parse(response.ids);
      var list = '';
      _.each(ids, function(result) {
      list += '<li>' + result.CustomerId + ' - ' + result.CustomerDescription + '</li>';
      });
      callback('<ul>' + list + '</ul>');

    } else {
      return "Cound't Fetch Customer Ids";
    }
  }).fail(function() {
    return "Cound't Fetch Customer Ids";
  });     
};
```